# Drawing pixel images with LWJGL

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, pixel, bytebuffer

I am at this moment trying to write a simple program using java's LWJGL.  When the program runs, it is suppose to give me a red screen at the beginning and anytime I press '1'.  If I press '2' it is suppose to give me a black to white gradient screen.  The program runs but when I press '2' it gives me this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of remaining buffer elements is 0, must be at least 3686400. Because at most 3686400 elements can be returned, a buffer with at least 3686400 elements is required, regardless of actual returned element count

```
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.throwBufferSizeException(BufferChecks.java:162)
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBufferSize(BufferChecks.java:189)
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBuffer(BufferChecks.java:230)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawPixels(GL11.java:1059)
at LWJGL.Lab1.render(Lab1.java:68)
at LWJGL.Game.gameLoop(Game.java:84)
at LWJGL.Game.<init>(Game.java:25)
at LWJGL.Lab1.<init>(Lab1.java:11)
at LWJGL.Lab1.main(Lab1.java:93)
```

I am not sure what I did wrong with the ByteBuffer to make it do this.  Here is my code.

```
package LWJGL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.util.*;

public class Lab1 extends Game
{
    private ByteBuffer raster;
    private int drawmode = 1;
    private int x,y;

    public void init()
    {
        raster= ByteBuffer.allocate(640*480*3);
        raster.asFloatBuffer();

        Display.setTitle("Tutorial 1: A simple moving rectangle");

        // Setup OpenGL
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
        glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

        //initialize the raster
        for(int i =0; i< raster.capacity(); i++){
            raster.put((byte) (((float)i)/(640*480*3)));
        }
    }

    public void update(long elapsedTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_1))
            drawmode = 1;

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_2))
            drawmode =2;

    }

    public void render()
    {
        // Render to the screen here
        glClearColor(1,0,0,1);  // Set the clear color
        // Clear the screen to the clear color (i.e. if the clear color
        // is red, the screen turns red);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (drawmode == 2) {
            // Save the old state so that you can set it back after you draw
            //GLint oldmatrixmode;
            boolean depthWasEnabled = glIsEnabled(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            //glGetIntegerv(GL_MATRIX_MODE,oldmatrixmode);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glPushMatrix(); glLoadIdentity();
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glPushMatrix(); glLoadIdentity();

            // Draw the array of pixels (This is where you draw the values
            // you have stored in the array 'raster')
            glRasterPos2f(-1,-1);
            GL11.glDrawPixels(640,480,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,raster);

            //Set the state back to what it was
            glPopMatrix();
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glPopMatrix();
            //glMatrixMode(oldmatrixmode);
            if (depthWasEnabled)
              glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }
        glFlush();
    }

    public void resized()
    {
        // We reset the viewport here.
        glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Lab1();
    }
}
```

The abstract class Game is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### You have a number of issues here:

1. `asFloatBuffer (...)` by itself does nothing. It returns another buffer that references the same data as your original buffer but using a different representation. If you do not use the return value, there is no reason to call it.
2. Your `ByteBuffer` is 1/4 the size it ought to be to store 640*480*3 floating-point components.

   - `GLfloat` is required to be 32-bit in OpenGL --> 4 bytes.
3. `ByteBuffer.put (...)` increments the "current" position of your buffer. This is the position that LWJGL uses when it writes data to your buffer.

   - If you do not `flip` your buffer, then your beginning position is the end of the buffer. LWJGL will overflow your buffer immediately.

---

Here is one possible solution to your problem, that does not require calling `raster.flip (...)` (because `rasterAsFloats` stores its position separately from `raster`):

```java
public void init()
{
    raster                     = ByteBuffer.allocate  (640*480*4*3);
    FloatBuffer rasterAsFloats = raster.asFloatBuffer ();

    Display.setTitle("Tutorial 1: A simple moving rectangle");

    // Setup OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
    glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

    //initialize the raster
    for(int i =0; i< rasterAsFloats.capacity(); i++){
        rasterAsFloats.put ((((float)i)/(640*480*3)));
    }
}
```

#### Update:

I never said the code would actually produce a gradient like you wanted. Just that it would fix your crash problem. Here is some code that *may* produce a gradient, it should be good enough to get you started at least:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < rasterAsFloats.capacity (); i+=3) {
  float luminance = ((float)(i/(640 * 3))/480.0f);
  rasterAsFloats.put (luminance); // R
  rasterAsFloats.put (luminance); // G
  rasterAsFloats.put (luminance); // B
}
```

Comment: This almost fixed everything.  Now it doesn't crash when I click '2', but when I do there are two problems.  1) Only part of the lower left screen changes, the rest is still red making me think that the ByteBuffer is still not large enough. and 2) the new image in the lower left is not a black to white gradient but looks more like the fuss on a old television.  This might be because the buffer is in Big enden mode.  I will look more into it but please post another answer if one comes to mind.

Comment: also of note: I had to change raster                     = ByteBuffer.allocate  (640*480*4*3);  to raster                     = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect  (640*480*4*3); for it to work.

Comment: @ThomasHolladay: See my updated answer, if that still does not help I can always look into it more tomorrow when I am actually awake.

Comment: I made the corrections and the image is now black and white lines which is something.  The changed image is still too small though.  I am going to run it by some friends of mine tomorrow as well.